# Python Seaborn: getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to plot

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I'm working with a dataframe that only contains two columns, one categorical `Peril` and one numerical `Frequency`. I am trying to create a bar chart but I keep getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

when I run the following line:

`sns.catplot(data='df', x='Frequency', y='Peril', kind='bar')`

I've successfully plotted using this code before. I even went back and tried it in the old file and it works fine. I was originally thinking that maybe `Frequency` was being stored as a string instead of an integer, but when I ran `df.info()` it returned

```
RangeIndex: 36 entries, 0 to 35
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Peril        36 non-null object
Frequency    36 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 656.0+ bytes
```

Currently stuck on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check the difference between `data='df'` and `data=df`

Comment: Wow I feel dumb not realizing that, especially when I did it correctly before. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your dataframe variable is wrapped in quotes when it should not be. Remove the quotes and it should work.